# Is it possible to know the length of std::wostringstream before calling .str()?

Tags: c++, c++11, wostringstream

I am looking into **std::wostringstream** and how to properly use it. I was wondering if there is any way of knowing the length of the constructed string beforehand? I tried searching for information on MSDN and http://en.cppreference.com/w/ and finally google but couldn't find what I was looking for.

For example if I pass a reference of **wostringstream** to a function, is it possible the function to know if the stream is empty or if not and how long is it without doing a copy by calling **.str()**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`tellp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/tellp) member function, which returns the output position indicator of the associated stream buffer. For instance:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::wostringstream oss;
    oss << L"Hello" << " World!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << oss.tellp();
}
```

Here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4zgAes%2444).

Comment: While this will probably work, it's definitely not guaranteed.

Comment: @JamesKanze Could you elaborate why it's not guaranteed to work?

Comment: @ChristianRau I'd ask the opposite question: why do you think it should work.  `wostream::tellp()` returns a `pos_type` (which is a class type); this converts to a `streamoff` (which is an integral type), but there's no indication as to what sort of mapping is involved, as long as the results are coherent.  (It is, of course, hard to make sense of the standards requirements here, especially since it requires `P(O(p)) == p`, where `P` is a `pos_type`, `O` is `streamoff`, and `p` is an instance of `P`.  Which is, of course, manifestly impossible, since `P` is required to hold more information.)